# CSV writer stops at one row

Tags: python, csv

How do you write all data to CSV? Currently this is creating one complete row. But does not move on. I tried writer.rows, I tried "Cards".

```
Cards = Card.where(q='set.name:generations supertype:pokemon')
for card in Cards:

    card = (card.name, card.types, card.supertype, card.subtypes, card.number, card.rarity, card.nationalPokedexNumbers, card.id, card.set.name, card.set.series)
    rows = card
    

with open ('pokemontest3.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file)

    csvwriter.writerow(rows)
```

Comment: If your `with` block is really outside the `for` loop (it is not indented to be inside the for loop), then it only executes once. Switch it up: `with open` the file, then put the `for` loop inside it.

Comment: Your `for-loop` logic should be indented inside the `with` context manager. The `csvwriter.writerow(rows)` should be inside the `for-loop`

Comment: Does it write just that last row?

Answer (score 1):

You keep overwriting `rows` in your `for` loop. When its done, only the last card is in `rows`. If you run the loop after you've created the writer, you can just write as you go.

```
with open ('pokemontest3.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file)
    Cards = Card.where(q='set.name:generations supertype:pokemon')
    for card in Cards:
        card = (card.name, card.types, card.supertype, card.subtypes, card.number, card.rarity, card.nationalPokedexNumbers, card.id, card.set.name, card.set.series)
        csvwriter.writerow(card)
```